# Can I clean up/reformat text with regex in a text editor?

Tags: regex, sublimetext

Let's say I have a bunch of text like this:

```
"title": "Blog post headline",
"url": "http://urlofblogpost.com/article",

"title": "Blog post2 headline",
"url": "http://urlofblogpost.com/article2",
```

or like this (if I clean it up a bit):

```
Blog post headline
http://urlofblogpost.com/article

Blog post2 headline
http://urlofblogpost.com/article2
```

Could I use search and replace in Sublime Text and change it to this?:

```
<a href="http://urlofblogpost.com/article">Blog post headline</a>
<a href="http://urlofblogpost.com/article2">Blog post2 headline</a>
```

Comment: @zx81 Hey, sorry, I haven't been at the computer. I actually forgot some stuff in the "dirty" text but with your explanations I managed to make some tweaks myself! Worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search: `"title":\s*"([^"]+)",?[\r\n]+"url":\s*"([^"]+)",?`

Replace: `<a href="$2">$1</a>`

In **[the Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eC5uK2/9)**, see the substitutions at the bottom.

**Explanation**

- `"title":` matches literal chars
- `\s*` matches optional whitespace
- `"` matches quote
- `([^"]+)` captures any chars that are not a quote to Group 1
- `",?` matches quote and optional comma
- `[\r\n]+` matches line breaks
- `"url":"` matches literal chars
- `\s*` matches optional whitespace
- `([^"]+)` captures any chars that are not a quote to Group 2
- `",?` matches quote and optional comma
- In the replacement, `$1` and `$2` insert the content matched by Groups 1 and 2

Comment: +1 from my side for quick reply. Add `\s*` in after `"url":` as well.

Comment: FYI: Added demo and explanation. :)

Comment: @Braj Thanks! You're right, `\s*` is more balanced with the earlier part of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for the second example,

**Regex:**

```
([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)(?=\n|$)
```

**Replacement string:**

```
<a href="\2">\1</a>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pS9tI3/4)

**Explanation:**

```
(                        group and capture to \1:
  [^\n]+                   any character except: '\n' (newline) (1
                           or more times)
)                        end of \1
\n                       '\n' (newline)
(                        group and capture to \2:
  [^\n]+                   any character except: '\n' (newline) (1
                           or more times)
)                        end of \2
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
 |                        OR
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                           the string
)                        end of look-ahead
```